# Rewrite rule for incoming urls

Tags: redirect, urls

**Part 1:** How do I get people visiting my blog with `http://example.com/archives/14073` redirect to `http://example.com/?p=14073`.

**Part 2:** What about when the incoming link is like this: `http://example.com/archives/14073?utm_campaign=Foo&utm_source=foo.com&utm_medium=email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved both parts:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archives/(.*)$ /\?p=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The `QSA` flag maintained the query string automagically.

**Most importantly**, I had to put it *above* the existing WordPress rewrite rules in order for it to work.